# Verify is there is an integer which satisfies a relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

how do I know if there is an integer $I_1$ which satisfies this relation $I_1=R_1+R_2I_2$? $I_1$, $I_2$ are unknown integers and $R_1$, $R_2$ are rational numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: $R_1, R_2$ can be *any* real numbers?  That isn't true.  That would require (if $I_2\ne 0$) then  $\frac {I_1}{I_2}=\frac {R_1}{I_2}+R_2$ be rational but there are obviously real number that would make it irrational.

Comment: Rather than underscores... you are asking how to know if $x+ny$ is an integer where $x,y$ are some known reals and $n$ is an integer?  Is performing the necessary arithmetic not an option?

Comment: So, are you *given* $I_2, R_1, R_2$ but not $I_1$.  Are you give $R_1, R_2$ but not the integers?

Comment: I find the question unclear. Are $R_1, R_2$ and $I_2$ fixed? Or is the question "are there real numbers $R_1, R_2$ and an integer $I_2$ such that $R_1+R_2I_2$ belongs to $\mathbb{Z}$?" Besides, I think you mean that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are real numbers which are not integers, otherwise the answer is trivial.

Comment: Looks like an excerpt from possibly a bigger problem where it says more about what those quantities are. If that is the case, please post the whole problem.

Comment: I think a legitimate question could be: Given $r_1, r_2$ two real numbers is there conditions so that integers $i_1, i_2$ exist so that $i_1 = r_1 + i_2r_2$?  But I don't want to put words in the OP's mouth.  But as is the question is unclear.

Comment: I know $R_1$ and $R_2$ but I don't know $I_1$ and $I_2$, so I'd like to know if there are integers $I_1$ and $I_2$ that satisfy that relation. $R_1$ may be any real non-negative real number, including 0 . $R_2$ cannot be 0 but may be any non-negative real number.

Comment: @fleablood, that is my question. I'm sorry the question was unclear.

Comment: Not nesc.  If say $R_1 = R_2 = \pi$ then $R_1 + I_2 R_2 = \pi(I_2 + 1)$ which can never be an integer (unless $I_2 = -1)$

Comment: And if $R_1$ and $R_2$ are rational numbers?